# Django: static files

Tags: django, django-templates

When i try to serve up images from within my blog the template is looking in

```
[26/Mar/2012 10:33:42] "GET /blog/images/coke.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6153
```

However when i load up images from a flat page the template looks in

[26/Mar/2012 10:33:42] "GET /blog/images/coke.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6153

I think this is because i need to add something to my urls.py file with my blog app so that it knows what my static URL is rather than looking in the blog/images folder.

Im using the tag:

```
src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/header.png"
```

My settings.py has:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/export/mailgrp4_a/sc10jbr/WWWdev/dbe/djangostatic/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/export/mailgrp4_a/sc10jbr/WWWdev/dbe/static/',
```

My blog url.py has:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('dbe.blog.views',
(r"^(\d+)/$", "post"),
(r"^add_comment/(\d+)/$", "add_comment"),
(r"^delete_comment/(\d+)/$", "delete_comment"),
(r"^delete_comment/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "delete_comment"),
(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "month"),
(r"", "main"),
)
```

My main url.py has:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

What do i need to add?

My updated blog url.py has:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from dbe.blog.models import *
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = patterns('dbe.blog.views',
(r"^(\d+)/$", "post"),
(r"^add_comment/(\d+)/$", "add_comment"),
(r"^delete_comment/(\d+)/$", "delete_comment"),
(r"^delete_comment/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "delete_comment"),
(r"^month/(\d+)/(\d+)/$", "month"),
(r"", "main"),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My updated main url.py has:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from dbe.blog.models import *
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Can anyone else help with this, im really stuck even after following the help below. Is there anything i can use to help debug and diagnose the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are developing you can add this to urls.py. Once you finish you must configure the web server to serve static files.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
         url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you miss following things:

settings.py (maybe `syncdb` is needed)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
...
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'django.core.context_processors.static',
...
)
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

run `collectstatic` command

also there's doc page with all details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/

Comment: Which urls.py should i add this to? I've added it to both and it made no difference. Ill post both appended urls.py above. I may have edited incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: `+= staticfiles_urlpatterns()` is needed only in main urls.py.
Did yout run `collectstatic`? What do you see when you open directly url of some static file?

Comment: Ok, collectstatic has put all my files in djangostatic successfully. My flat pages can access the images perfectly, because they are not an app? In the terminal when i open my home page (flatpage) my images load from: [23/Mar/2012 16:10:54] "GET /static/images/header.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
However when i load my blog page the images load from: [23/Mar/2012 16:11:00] "GET /blog/images/header.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3630. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way the image would be requested at `/blog/images/header.png` is if `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is evaluated to an empty string. The only way that would happen is if it's not set in the context, and the only way that would happen is if you don't have the staticfiles template context processor included:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

Comment: Still, what I said holds true. If you have that line, then for whatever reason, it's not being applied. You could have accidentally overridden `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` somewhere else, or your server is not running off up-to-date code where this setting is present. Delete all *.pyc files and make sure you fully stop whatever server you're running and then start it up again.